# How to pass username as parameter recursively from a file in SecretStringTemplate (rotation secret cloudformation template code)?

Tags: boto3, aws-secrets-manager, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I am writing a cloudformation template to use the lambda function deployed by AWS to rotate the secret creds of Aurora RDS after a set period of time.

But i need to pass on through the below template like 3 times recursively to create 3 different user secrets. For this i used count and Pylate macros.

Below is the code:-

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: |
  Aurora DB users rotation mecahnism via autocreated rotation lambda.

Transform: 
  - AWS::SecretsManager-2020-07-23
  - Count
  - PyPlate

Parameters:
  pEnv:
    Type: String
  pResAurSg:
    Type: String
  pDbUserNameCount:
    Type: Number
  pDbUserName:
    Type: String


Conditions:
  cDbUserNameCheck:
    Count: !Ref pDbUserNameCount
    Fn::Not:
      - Fn::Equals:
          - |
            #!PyPlate
            import ast
            output = ast.literal_eval(params['pDbUserName'])[%d-1]['pName']
          - ignore

Resources:

  rRDSInstanceRotationSecret:
    Count: !Ref pDbUserNameCount
    Condition: cDbUserNameCheck%d
    Type: AWS::SecretsManager::Secret
    Properties:
      Name: |
          #!PyPlate
          import ast
          output = {}
          output['Fn::Sub'] = f"{ast.literal_eval(params['pDbUserName'])[%d-1]['pName']}"
      KmsKeyId: "alias/SecretsManager_KMSKey"
      GenerateSecretString:
        SecretStringTemplate: '{"username": "rs_ro1", "masterarn": "<arn"}'
        GenerateStringKey: "password"
        PasswordLength: 16
        ExcludeCharacters: "\"@/\\"
      Tags: <tags>
...
```

And below is the parameter file:-

```
  "aur_dbuser_params": {
    "Dbusername": [
      {
        "pName": "user1",
        "pusername": "rs_su"
      },
      {
        "pName": "user2",
        "pusername": "rs_ro1"
      },
      {
        "pName": "user3",
        "pusername": "rs_ro2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Not able to pass these usernames in parmeter file recursively using count macro to "SecretStringTemplate" in template as it doesn't accepts JSON. so did try out JSON.stringify as well but that didn't worked.

How can i pass username to "SecretStringTemplate" as i did for "Name" parameter using Pylate in properties for recursive calling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i was able to find a workaround for this, particularly using python dictionary:-

```
      GenerateSecretString:
        SecretStringTemplate: |
          #!PyPlate
          import ast,json
          creds_dict = {}
          creds_dict["username"] = ast.literal_eval(params['pDbUserName'])[%d-1]['pUsername']
          creds_dict["masterarn"] = '<arn>'
          output = json.dumps(creds_dict)
        GenerateStringKey: "password"
```